# android app crash since fab change

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I am getting this error log since I changed a few things at my `floating action button` (and added another one) :

[image: error log]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_assets_overview" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFABadd"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabRemove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFABremove"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabHint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_lightbulb_outline_white_24dp"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFABhint"/>
```

Can somebody please tell me what I did wrong? I guess it has something to do with the color change. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your complete XML file? - the error points to `tint` which uses the `app:` namespace.

Comment: Can you add a line `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` - and see if this resolves the error - I see it is missing from your XML. This needs to be added in your out-most XML tag so that you may use `app:` in the wrapped components like the `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: jep its is there but I don't know why it wasn't copied...

Comment: Okay I got the solution for this little problem just in case someone wants to know how:
I simply had to remove this line from each of my floating action buttons since it was unnecessary:

    app:tint="@color/white"

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

1) Declare the XML namespace's at the top of the XML file:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

2) Declare your Floating Action Button as so:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myID"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/myColour"
    android:src="@drawable/myIcon"
```

I hope that this helps.